# Cross-Compiling Curl with SSL Support

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile Curl with SSL but I'm not able to.

Here is what I did for OpenSSL:

```
CROSS=arm-linux-gnuabi
./Configure linux-generic32 shared --prefix=/home --openssldir=/home
make CC="${CROSS}-gcc" AR="${CROSS}-ar r" RANLIB="${CROSS}-ranlib" LD="${CROSS}-ld" MAKEDEPPROG="${CROSS}-gcc" PROCESSOR=ARM
make CC="${CROSS}-gcc" AR="${CROSS}-ar r" RANLIB="${CROSS}-ranlib" INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/lz/sysroot install
```

As a result, in /home/lz/sysroot/home, I got:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:14 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:04 certs
drwxrwxr-x 3 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:16 include
drwxrwxr-x 4 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:16 lib
drwxrwxr-x 6 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:03 man
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:14 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz  11K Feb 25 08:14 openssl.cnf
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:04 private
drwxrwxr-x 5 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:05 share

[20150225 08:18:26] lz@lz:~/sysroot$ ls -lh home/lib/
total 6.1M
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:14 engines
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 3.1M Feb 25 08:14 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lz lz   18 Feb 25 08:14 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lz lz 2.0M Feb 25 08:14 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 574K Feb 25 08:14 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lz lz   15 Feb 25 08:14 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lz lz 442K Feb 25 08:14 libssl.so.1.0.0
drwxrwxr-x 2 lz lz 4.0K Feb 25 08:04 pkgconfig

[20150225 08:20:35] lz@lz:~/sysroot$ ls -lh home/include/openssl/ | grep "\(ssl\|crypto\)"
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz  28K Feb 25 08:14 crypto.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 6.8K Feb 25 08:14 kssl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 6.8K Feb 25 08:14 opensslconf.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 3.9K Feb 25 08:14 opensslv.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 7.7K Feb 25 08:14 ossl_typ.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 3.8K Feb 25 08:14 ssl23.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz  12K Feb 25 08:14 ssl2.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz  33K Feb 25 08:14 ssl3.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 lz lz 146K Feb 25 08:14 ssl.h
```

But when I try to build Curl with SSL support, I can't get it work, I tried the following:

```
./configure --with-ssl --with-sysroot=/home/lz/sysroot --prefix=/home --host=${CROSS}
./configure --with-ssl --with-sysroot=/home/lz/sysroot/home --host=${CROSS}
./configure --with-ssl --prefix=/home/lz/sysroot/home --host=${CROSS}
./configure --with-ssl=/home/lz/sysroot/home --with-sysroot=/home/lz/sysroot --prefix=/home --host=${CROSS}
```

And I always get this warning:

```
checking whether to enable Windows native SSL/TLS (Windows native builds only)... no
checking whether to enable iOS/Mac OS X native SSL/TLS... no
checking for CRYPTO_lock in -lcrypto... no
checking for CRYPTO_add_lock in -lcrypto... no
checking for ssl_version in -laxtls... no
configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss, --with-axtls, --with-winssl, or --with-darwinssl to address this.
checking default CA cert bundle/path... configure: WARNING: skipped the ca-cert path detection when cross-compiling
no
```

And finally, SSL support is not activated:

```
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.38.1-20141105
  Host setup:       arm-linux-gnuabi
  Install prefix:   /home
  Compiler:         arm-linux-gnuabi-gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  ipv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP
```

I can't understand what's missing, and It's not enough verbose for me to find where Curl is actually looking for OpenSSL dir.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check (or paste here) related parts of config.log file. There, you can find what the configure script is checking to determine SSL support.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got: configure:21328: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR will be set to "/home/lz/sysroot/home/lib/pkgconfig"
configure:21540: checking for CRYPTO_lock in -lcrypto
configure:21562: arm-linux-gnuabi-gcc -o conftest -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -I/home/lz/sysroot/home/include -I/home/lz/sysroot/home/include/openssl  -L/home/lz/sysroot/home/lib conftest.c -lcrypto  -lrt >&5
/opt/crosstool/arm-linux-gnuabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnuabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnuabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Look at BR [recipe](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/libcurl/libcurl.mk). It could help to understand, how others cross-compile libcurl with OpenSSL support. Or just use Buildroot.

Comment: @Lazao - what platform are you targeting? I ask because there may be a specific tutorial available on the OpenSSL wiki when cross-compiling the OpenSSL library.

Comment: @Lazao - I think `--with-sysroot` is used to set the header and library path for C and C++ runtimes; and not an add on library like OpenSSL. For your purposes, you should be modifying `CFLAGS` with `-I`, `-L` and `-l` with the OpenSSL header path and library path.